# OpenDDS working Issues with Raspberry Pi

Tags: makefile, gnu, publish-subscribe, data-distribution-service, opendds

I am working on OpenDDS and trying to run messenger example on my Raspberry Pi . Example Messenger Worked on my Ubuntu setup but when i am trying to run it on my Raspberry Pi , it's not working .
there were no problem in **./configure** but when i ran the " make " command . I got the following error 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKsKd.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone coming to this in the future, building OpenDDS directly on a Raspberry Pi or similar is not advised. It's recommended to cross-compile using a regular computer and copy the results to the Pi. [There is a guide for doing this on the OpenDDS website.](http://opendds.org/quickstart/GettingStartedPi.html)